# Take screenshot of a specific area with Electron

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, electron, electron-packager, sharp

I am using Electron to create a Windows application that creates a fullscreen transparent overlay window. The purpose of this application is to:

- Take a snapshot of a specific area of the screen (by using a position - `X`,`Y` - and a size -`width`,`height`) at a certain frequency, for exemple every 5 seconds.
- Comparing current snapshot data with the previous one to detect changes.
- Trigger an action (e.g: running a script) when changes are detected.

*Example using Sciter: https://github.com/GirkovArpa/screenshot-delta-detector*

I am getting stuck on the screenshot capturing process.

I tried capturing the whole screen by using `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()` + drawing a frame in a `canvas` (`drawImage()`) + getting image data using `canvas.toDataURL()` then cropping (using [sharp](https://github.com/lovell/sharp).extract) the fullscreen image to get only my monitored area:

```js
setInterval(async () => {

  // Get fullscreen screenshot
  const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                    audio: false,
                    video: {
                        mandatory: {
                            chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
                            chromeMediaSourceId: sources[0].id, // screen 1
                            width: {
                                exact: screenWidth
                            },
                            height: {
                                exact: screenHeight
                            }
                        },
                    }
                });

  // Create hidden video tag
  const video = document.createElement('video');
  video.style.cssText = 'position:absolute;top:-10000px;left:-10000px;';

  // Event connected to stream
  video.onloadedmetadata = function () {
   // Set video ORIGINAL height (screenshot)
   video.style.height = this.videoHeight + 'px'; // videoHeight
   video.style.width = this.videoWidth + 'px'; // videoWidth

   video.play();

   // Create canvas
   const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
   canvas.width = this.videoWidth;
   canvas.height = this.videoHeight;
   const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
   // Draw video on canvas
   ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

   // Get area snapshot
   // crop full screenshot in area position + size
   const areaSnapshot = await cropImage(Buffer.from(canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1).replace('data:image/png;base64,', ''), 'base64'));

    // then comparing previous snapshot with current one 
    for (let i = 0; i < this.previousAreaSnapshot.length; i++) {
       if (previousAreaSnapshot[i] !== areaSnapshot[i]) {
           console.log("Change detected!")
       }
    }
  }

  video.srcObject = stream;
  document.body.appendChild(video);

}, 5000)

async function cropImage(fullScreenShot) {
   return await sharp(fullScreenShot)
                .extract({
                    width: 100,
                    height: 100,
                    left: 500,
                    top: 500,
                 })
                .toBuffer({ resolveWithObject: true })
                .then(({ data, info }) => data)
}
```

**Problem:** `areaSnapshot` is a correct image of the area but, due to compression on the full screenshot, my buffer is different when something change near the area (~30 pixels around the area). when comparing the two snapshots there are small differences due to compression algorithm rearranging close pixels in order to optimise full screenshot image weight (before cropping).
Also, making a full screenshot to just process a small part is very unoptimised and generating useless load on my CPU / GPU.

Screenshots (red dotted border element is the area):

- no changes on the area: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPwsQ.png
- changes near the area (but not inside): https://i.imgur.com/hbujtuZ.png

*(The window in my screenshot doesn't have shadow. I also tried using simple pixel change at 2 pixels from the area, it also detected a change. I've made a diff check between the two snapshots using dedicated tools, it's clearly due to compression)*

Other test to confirm that compression is creating changes:
https://i.imgur.com/o4Xjl3x.png

Note: I also tried to short this implementation by using `desktopCapturer.getSources` with `thumbnailSize` parameter: same result.

So my questions are:

- is there a way to directly screenshot a specific area of the screen without having to take the whole screen first ?
- is it possible to get raw data of the screenshot with no compression to prevent such side effects on my cropped image ?

Any help would be very much appreciated.